# exporting typdef function pointer to dll

Tags: c++, dll

I'm working on an exercise that gives me a header file that declares several functions and asks me to create a DLL that will be dynamically loaded that can export these functions.  The hard part for me is that the header file declares the functions as function pointers which is really confusing to me.  Here is how one is delcared:

```
typedef int32_t* (__stdcall* T_func)(int32_t* a);
```

The instructions say that my DLL should should export the function "func" and I can do it however I wish as long as the DLL implements the interface (shown above).

I can't create a function T_func because it's a typedef, and I can't create a function called func with type T_func.  I'm confused on how I'm supposed to declare a function based on what they've given me.  Create a function called func with the same input and return types as T_func?

Answer (score 0):

You just declare a function in the DLL as:

```
int32_t* __stdcall func(int32_t* a);
```

Then, in the client code, you bind dinamically with:

```
T_func pFunc = (T_func)GetProcAddress(hModule, "func");
```

Here's where the typedef comes in handy. The DLL code does not use it.

**UPDATE**: Your question is tagged C++, you you probably need the function defined as `extern "C"` or else you'll get a C++ mangled name. And since you are probably using MS-Windows

```
extern "C" {
declspec(dllexport) int32_t* __stdcall func(int32_t* a);
}
```

Comment: Can I put the extern "C" around my function definition?  Also, it seems to compile fine, but the .exe used to test the DLL says it's not a valid module.

Comment: Hey I'm doing the same exercise, did you ever figure out why this is?